# Programmatically login to site with Apache basic authentication from WPF .net application

Tags: wpf, apache, internet-explorer, basic-authentication, autologin

We have a requirement to open a web site URL in default browser of the client machine from our WPF application. All this time we were using simple `Process.Start(URL)` and it was working fine. Until now where one of customer has this "URL" behind basic authentication. The site they want us to browse using URL is hosted on Apache web server. From what I know, if we have `https://username:password@domain.com` it directly takes us in site without the username/password challenge and it works fine in Chrome and Firefox, however newer version on IE stopped supporting it for security reasons.

Can someone suggest some alternate approach to achieve same considering following objectives ?

1. List item
2. Browse to URL with passing in username password.
3. Open default browser in client's desktop machine.
4. Don't want to user browser control
5. At minimum should work in 3 browsers - IE, Firefox and Chrome
6. We cannot make changes to client desktop's machine, so solution shouldn't require any special settings.

Comment: I think this is going to be very difficult for you to accomplish, essentially you're looking at an automation scenario with IE.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for developers from the Microsoft Support site : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

> Workarounds for application and Web site developers
>
> URLs that are opened by objects that call WinInet or Urlmon functions
>
> For objects that use an HTTP or an HTTPS URL that includes user
>   information when they call a WinInet or Urlmon function such as
>   InternetOpenURL, rewrite the object to use one of the following
>   methods to send user information to the Web site: Use the
>   InternetSetOption function and include the following option flags:
>   INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD Note For these
>   flags, the InternetSetOption option must have a handle returned by the
>   InternetConnect function. Therefore, if the application uses the
>   InternetOpenUrl function, modify the application to use the
>   InternetConnect, HttpOpenRequest and HttpSendRequest WinInet
>   functions. For more information about how to use these functions,
>   visit the following Microsoft Web sites:
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa384363
>
> http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa384233
>
> http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384247.aspx Use the
>   IAuthenticate Interface. For more information about how to use the
>   IAuthenticate Interface, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775080.aspx

Was this option tried ?